USB issues when powering RPI3 from Arduino Nano Every
I'm powering on/off an RPI3 A+ with a high-side power switch controlled by arduino gpio. I'm switching with it the high side going to RPI PP2 pad.
It works for the first several times but after some (4-5) power cycles, say 15 mins apart, the usb devices attached to RPI won't work anymore, D+ stays high at 2.1V and I need to power cycle arduino to recover from this issue.
Can you help to root-cause this?
EDIT: RPI is powered off after normal OS shutdown. Also missed saying that 2.1V D+ value is seen at the USB hub attached to RPI

Not an answer to your question, but wanted to let you know there is a chance that powering down your RPI3 with out shutting down the OS first may corrupt your SDCard.

What are you powering off the RPI3's USB ports? Guessing, there might be a current limitation you are exceeding. For example, A USB 2.0 port is only required to supply 500mA. After that, many computers will limit current  by dropping the voltage to protect them selves.

Sorry, you said D+, not V+. Still, would be good to know what USB device is connected. Might also consider the consequences of interrupting the power USB devices. USB communications is very complex. If USB discovery fails, then there may be no subsequent USB communications. Try this: Upon detecting a failed state, unplug the USB peripheral and plug it back in again in an attempt to force a new USB discovery sequence of events.

I added details in the question

Please [edit] your question to add a schematic. -- Is the USB hub self-powered or bus-powered? The schematic should show that in the former case. -- Since you state that the connection between Arduino and RPi is just the high-side switch, what effect has the power cycle of the Arduino on this part of the circuit? You might need to measure, optimally with an oscilloscope. -- Does removing the high-side switch and power cycling manually the same way create the same effect?

It is the expected way to add clarifications to the question, don't be attempted to "answer" in comments. This is not a forum. To notify commenters, you can use the character "@" directly followed by user name, but only one per comment.
